# How to Mac OS Yosemite PostgreSQL create database without username and password

Tags: database, macos, postgresql, authentication

Is it possible to make a database without any username and password?

I would like to use this database read write by code to generate tables and data. I have to always set username and password all the time and remove it later on. I'm guessing there could be a possible way to achieve this. If possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one without a password, But I am pretty sure you're still going to need to use a username. Most *nix systems use your local username to authenticate in order to sign in to the default postgres user, which doesn't have a password.

Login to postgres and make a new user without a password

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

or

```
sudo -u username psql postgres
```

psql=#

```
CREATE ROLE newusername createdb;
```

or if you choose to add a password later

```
ALTER ROLE newusername WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'thepassword' createdb;
```